# Create a sliver that contains a column of slivers

Tags: flutter

Is there a sliver that displays a list of slivers as a column? Basically a `SliverList` that has a `slivers` field  instead of the `children` field.

The reason why I need this: I want wrap two slivers into a single sliver that can be put into a `CustomScrollView`. Of course, the workaround is to put the two slivers separately into the `CustomScrollView`, but that's what I want to avoid doing.

Comment: what is silver ?

Answer (score 8):

flutter 3.13 add [SliverMainAxisGroup](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverMainAxisGroup-class.html) and [SliverCrossAxisGroup](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverCrossAxisGroup-class.html)

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverMainAxisGroup(
            slivers: <Widget>[
                Widget(),
                Widget(),
            ],
        ),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `MultiSliver` widget from my package [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools)

Comment: Thanks! This library is just what I needed, now I don't need to add horizontal padding and maxWidth to each individual sliver.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap it into a `CustomScrollView` inside a `SliverToBoxAdapter`.

`shrinkWrap: true` and `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` solved my problem.

```
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(),
          SliverFillRemaining(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I have no success with this to make app bar floating.

Comment: While this works, I believe it will remove the performance benefits of using Slivers.